# Android Navigation Drawer selected item is totally overlayed

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I am testing first time an App with the new Navigation Drawer with the Material Design library.

My problem is, that when I select an item, then the whole selected item inclusive the icon are fully overlayed, like in the pictures shown below. 
What can be my mistake here? I have tried several things, whitout success.

[image]

[image]

This is the XML with the Navigation Drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"
        />
```

in @layout/nav_header_main you can create your xml file contains header part for navigation drawer.

for drawer_item_background--
create xml file in drawable folder and paste below code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#48607B" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

app:menu contains menu item contained in navigation drawer.
this may be look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
            android:title="Dashboard" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_m3_account"
            android:title="@string/my_account_fragment" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notification_settings"
            android:title="Notification Settings" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
            android:title="FAQ" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terms_condition"
            android:title="Terms &amp; Conditions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
            android:title="Privacy Policy" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:title="Log Out" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Didn't help. Now all items got the background color.

My problem is, that when an item is selected, than I can't see the icon and text under the selection.

Answer (score 0):

After try to reduce the External Libraries, I found out that this library was the problem:

> it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip

But I dont know how to repair it. So I will remove this lib.